# Trouble Displaying Integer Within JLabel With HTML Line Breaking

Tags: java, line, jlabel

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JLabel label = new JLabel();

frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

int num;
String labelText = "<html>" + num + "<br/></html>";
label.setText(labelText);
```

This is my problem. I am trying to display the int num in a JLabel with a line breaker. Unfortunately, the numbers just overlay on each other resulting in a big black box. This is the product of regenerating the random number multiple times. [image]

I have tried all I can and I am very confused. Can anyone help?

Comment: It appears you are placing many JLabels on top of each other.  Can you edit your question and add your code which places the JLabels in their parent container?

Comment: I'm fairly sure some other part of your code is responsible for what you're seeing.  An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would be helpful.  Perhaps there is a line of code where you are adding new JLabels to existing JLabels (instead of adding them to the content pane)?